# Azure board bug has state "resolved" after pull request instead of "closed"

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, agile, azure-boards

The Azure DevOps Board works with pull requests. The stories are always automatically set to the status "Closed" at the PR, as desired. The problem now is that the status of the work item bug is set to "Resolved" instead of "Closed" after the PR, which means that the item is no longer visible on the board.

I have tried to correct a setting in the PR, as well as in the process settings of the board, however I can't find a suitable place how this can be solved.
If the item bug is moved manually on the board, it has the status "closed" as expected.

Settings: We use a copy of the "Agile" process for the project.

Question: How do I configure the project/board so that a bug that is closed by the PR has the status "Closed" instead of "resolved"?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I configure the project/board so that a bug that is closed by the PR has the status "Closed" instead of "resolved"?

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can custom the work item state when completing the Pull Request.

For a workaround, you can disable the option: **Complete associated work items after merging** when completing Pull Request.

[image]

Then you can modify the Pull Request description with the following format: `Closed: #workitemid`

For example:

[image]

Then when you complete the pull request, the work item state will change to closed.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Set work item state in pull request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/notifications/add-links-to-work-items?view=azure-devops#set-work-item-state-in-pull-request)

I can fully understand your requirement. Here is an existing Suggestion ticket about the feature request: [Ability to configure target work item state after completing PR](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ability-to-configure-target-work-item-state-after/1200823)